# Getting error: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'. after upgrading to Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, jvm

After updating Android Studio version to 2022.2.1 I started to get this error when trying to compile the project:

> Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
> Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain

My gradle:
compileSdk 33

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdk 23
    targetSdk 33

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            arguments = ["room.incremental": "true"]
        }
    }

    consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

How to fix this error?

Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1
Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.9862592, built on March 31, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 13.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you updated `Gradle` to version `8.0.0` along with the Flamingo 2022.2.1 update, then you need to update the `JDK` to version `17`

You can see the compatibility table [here](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin#compatibility-8-0-0).

The following code in app level build.gradle should solve your problem:

```
android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibilityJavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibilityJavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. My min SDK is 23. Do you think setting Java 17 in compileOptions and kotlinOptions will still be ok?

Comment: I checked, and it works well with API 23

Comment: Seems to work! Do you know what `compileOptions ` and `kotlinOptions` do?  I thought that setting java version to 17 would result in code being not working on old versions of Android that run older version of Java. Maybe that is not what it is?

Comment: `CompileOptions`  is Java compilation options and `kotlinOptions`  is Kotlin compilation options.
`sourceCompatibility` is the language level of the Java source code,
`targetCompatibility` and `jvmTarget` is the target version of the generated JVM bytecode.
The code will work in older versions of the API thanks to [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java11-minimal-support-table).
Probably, the java version upgrade was done to increase build performance using Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for Android Studio Giraffe

As per [This Toolchain Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-configure-project.html?utm_campaign=gradle-jvm-toolchain&utm_medium=kgp&utm_source=warnings#gradle-java-toolchains-support)

Adding this in the app gradle file fixed the issue for me.

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"

    }

    //important
    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(18)
    }
```