# Android Studio Kapt error: app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin compileDebugJavaWithJavac jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle, kapt

> Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
>
> > 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.7) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target
> > compatibility should be set to the same Java version.   Consider using
> > JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain

[image: Gradle error]

Environment:

Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2    Gradle: 8.0     Gradle JDK: JetBrains 17.0.6    Kotlin: 1.8.10

compileSdk = 34     targetSdk = 34

```
 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    //tried both of the below
    kotlin{
        jvmToolchain(17)
    }
    /*kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }*/
```

composeOptions {
kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
}

Plugins:

```
plugins {
  id("com.android.application") version "8.1.2" apply false
  id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.10" apply false
  id ("dagger.hilt.android.plugin") version "2.48" apply false
  kotlin("kapt") version "1.8.10" apply false
```

}

Similar errors were discussed, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76033964/getting-error-execution-failed-for-task-appkaptgeneratestubsdebugkotlin-af). But in my case, both are set to the same version - 17! I did try setting to 18 and changing the Gradle JDK to Amazon Coretto 18, no difference.

Per [compiler compatibility](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-compiler#1.5.3), no compatibility issues between kotlin compiler 1.4.3 and kotlin 1.8.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What error says that you are using version 1.7 rather 17

Here is `your mistake`. you have `declared 1.7`

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
```

But the Change is just remove **_ in between 1 and 7** and your problem must solved.

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
```

It's typo error I could say. Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: argh! right, thanks.